# Docker Swarm container cannot connect to its Docker host, connection times out

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm, docker-container

long story short:
Container C on Docker Swarm host A can access Nginx (`deploy mode:global`) on Docker Swarm host B but not on Docker Swarm host A via Docker host's IP, `connection timed out`.

Long story:
I have a Docker Swarm with 3 hosts. All Docker containers are running on a `scope:swarm` and `driver:overlay` network, called `internal_network`.
On the swarm I have also 3 Nginx (`deploy mode: global`) running. The Nginx have the default network set to `internal_network` but also `ports` configuration with `target:80,published:80,protocol:tcp,mode:host` (and other ports). The idea is that connections to the Docker swarm hosts are forwarded to the Nginx containers and then forwarded (reverse-proxied) to the Docker containers running on the swarm such as GitLab, Mattermost, and others.
Moreover, the Docker swarm hosts have `keepalived` configured to share the same IP (fail over) - so no matter what Docker host this shared IP is assigned to, there is always an Nginx running to accept incoming requests.
I am using Oracle Linux 8 (kernel 5.4.17 el8uek) and Docker 20.10.12. Docker is configured with `icc: false` and `userland-proxy: false`.

In the following example `addr.foo` resolves to `shared ip`.

What works:

- The shared IP is properly shared between the Docker hosts, once the IP owning host goes down, another takes over the shared IP - however, the problem seems not to be related to `keepalived` as it occurs with the Docker hosts' IPs too.
- From external clients it is possible to connect to Nginx (on shared IP or Docker host IP) and being reverse-proxied to a Docker container such as GitLab or Mattermost
- There is also a PostgreSQL running on the same stack and `internal_network` and Mattermost can communicate with that PostgreSQL instance on the `internal_network`.
- On any Docker swarm host it is possible to run `curl https://addr.foo` and `curl https://<shared ip>` and to access Nginx and the reverse-proxied Docker container
- On any Docker swarm host it is possible to run `curl https://<host ip>` and access Nginx and the reverse-proxied Docker container
- From within a Docker container (e.g. Nginx, GitLab, Mattermost) it is possible to run `curl https://addr.foo` or `curl https://<shared IP>` when the shared IP is not hosted by the Docker host that is hosting the Docker container itself.

What does not work:

- From within a Docker container (e.g. Nginx, GitLab, Mattermost) it is not possible to run `curl` and point to the Docker swarm host that is hosting the container. Curl (the container, docker) resolves the IP of its own Docker swarm host (e.g. `curl https://<Docker host name>`) which is correct but then the connection times out.
- From within a Docker container ([...]) it is not possible to run `curl` and point to the shared IP when the shared IP is hosted by the Docker host that is running the container. The `curl` connection times out when accessing the containers Docker host.

So from inside a container it is not possible to connect to the the containers Docker host's IP but to other Docker hosts' IPs. The network interface `ens192` on all Docker hosts is in firewall-zone `public` with all necessary ports open, external access works.

So my problem is: From within a Docker container it is not possible to establish a connection to the Docker host that is hosting the Docker container but it is possible to connect to another host.

On host docker host 1 with `addr.foo` resolving to docker host 2:

```
docker exec -it <nginx container id> curl https://addr.foo
[...] valid response
docker exec -it <nginx container id> curl https://<docker host 2>
[...] valid response
docker exec -it <nginx container id> curl https://<docker host 1>
connection timed out
```

Why do I need it:
Mattermost authenticates users via GitLab. Therefore, Mattermost needs to connect to GitLab. When Mattermost and GitLab are running on the same Docker swarm host, Mattermost cannot connect to GitLab.

What I do not want to do:
Restrict GitLab and Mattermost to not run on the same swarm host.

I also tried to move interface `docker_gwbridge` to firewall-zone `trusted` which led to the problem that the Docker containers did not start up.

I hope that this is enough information to get the idea.

Comment: Without the userland proxy, the iptables rules would need to implement a hairpin nat. I'm not sure that's built into the default rules.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer here I guess: [Docker Userland Proxy](https://www.ipspace.net/kb/DockerSvc/40-userland-proxy.html).

> In the previous section we identified two scenarios where Docker cannot use iptables NAT rules to map a published port to a container service:
>
> - When a container connected to another Docker network tries to reach the service (Docker is blocking direct communication between Docker networks);
> - When a local process tries to reach the service through loopback interface.

This is what `userland-proxy` is for and setting it to `true` (default) enables the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When communicating between containers you use the service name of the docker service not the host IP .

Try from cli of one container ping the other containers based on the service name. If no reply then they are not on the same overlay network.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar problem. In my case, nginx did not correctly determine the ip address of the container. An explicit indication of the nginx's directive helped:

```
resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
```